# Limit height of header-background-video?

Tags: css, video, background, fullscreen

I am working on a background video placed *in* a header. The header only has an height of 100%-257px, so that the rest of the page gets visible upon loading the page. 
However, I can't get the video to be a full background *within* the header. It always overflows the header container when in full-size. Am I missing some piece of css? 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Html:

```
<header id="home">
        <div id="videoBackground">
            <video loop="loop" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" poster="Images/posterImg.png" id="videoBackgroundVideo">
                <source type="video/mp4" src="Images/BillVid.mp4">
            </video>    
        </div>
        <h1> This is a title</h1>
        <h2> This is a subtitle</h2>
        <div id="welcomeMessage">
            <h3> Welcome at <span>My Page</span></h3>
            <img src="Images/LogoRoundWhite.png" id="homeLogoWhite" style="border-style:none;" />
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    min-height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    height: calc(100% - 257px);
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#videoBackground {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -10;
}

#videoBackgroundVideo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
               transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Can you fork that up in a fiddle and please add a valid url for the 'video'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
header {
    position:relative;
}
```

absolute positioned elements will position themselves in relation to the closest parent element with position:relative;

If this isnt present it will just position itself in relation to the body tag i believe, which is also why overflow:hidden may not be having an effect.

Comment: Fantastic idea Moose! I was also sure that the #videoBackgroundVideo was not listening to it's parent, but didn't understand why. Great to know that it will listen to the closest parent with position:relative. 
Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Remove `min-height: 100%;` from `#videoBackgroundVideo` element.

```css
header{
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    min-height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    height: calc(100% - 257px);
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#videoBackground {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -10;
}

#videoBackgroundVideo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
               transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<header id="home">
        <div id="videoBackground">
            <video loop="loop" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" poster="Images/posterImg.png" id="videoBackgroundVideo">
                <source type="video/mp4" src="Images/BillVid.mp4">
            </video>    
        </div>
        <h1> This is a title</h1>
        <h2> This is a subtitle</h2>
        <div id="welcomeMessage">
            <h3> Welcome at <span>My Page</span></h3>
            <img src="Images/LogoRoundWhite.png" id="homeLogoWhite" style="border-style:none;" />
        </div>
    </header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/xk8henbo/1/

Comment: @Menno, Check and let me know if you need any help. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried this myself, however it didn't work as I wished. When I removed the min-height, it did correctly show the video until the end of the box. However, it also resized the video in such a way that there would be empty spaces on the left and right, and on top. 
But with the other answer I got, I managed to make it work. Thanks for your help though @VSM! :)

Comment: @Menno, Ok, It's my pleasure. Thanks